# Laying out Rectangle() Views in SwiftUI inside of ForEach?

Tags: swiftui

So, I am trying to layout Rectangle shapes on a SwiftUI View, like this:

[image]

I am not sure how to best go about this. Any suggestion?

EDIT:

I added this and it now works. Is there a better more proper solution?

extension CGRect: Hashable {

```
public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(NSCoder.string(for: self).hashValue)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error saying you the reason. I recommend you to create a class. So you will able to make it BindableObject if needed and add more properties like Color if needed

```
class RectangleModel: NSObject, Identifiable {

    var rect: CGRect

    init(rect: CGRect) {
        self.rect = rect
    }

}
```

Or the best is to create one more model(like RectangleStore) that will be a BindableObject and will contain array of RectangleModels. It will be much flexible